# Default value of a Schema field is not set in Component for multi value fields

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, keyword

We have an embedded Schema `Link` used in many other Schemas as a multi value. One of the fields in this `Link` Schema is `Target Type` which is a drop-down select from Category. The Category has 2 Keywords:

1. Same Window
2. New Window.

In the `Link` Schema, I have set `Same Window` as the default value.

While creating a new Component with any Schema using `Link`, I am getting the `Same Window` value, in the drop-down for `Target Type` field as expected.

However when I add another instance of `Link` in same Component by clicking  `+`, I am getting the `New Window` value instead of the `Same Window` value. This happens for every new instance.

Is this a bug? As a workaround, I have renamed the Keywords to `01 Same Window` and `02 New Window` and this works well.

I can see this question posted [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/default-value-in-drop-down-list-of-embeddable-multivalued-field-is-appearing-inc) already, but no resolution. And I believe it works well if we do not use the Keywords but normal text values.

Comment: Can you update the title of your question

Comment: what is the relationship to DXA? or can that tag be removed?

Comment: @PankajGaur : Done, Thanks. 
BartKoopman : No relationship, tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the similar issue and Tridion created a hotfix CME_2013.1.0.88281 for us which enables multivalued fields to be populated with default value even after the first instance. It works with everything apart from keywords and categories. I would suggest not using categories and keywords and then it will work fine as long as you have the hotfix.

We also raised request for categories and keywords because after the first instance, the default value is not populated if we use category and keywords. It is accepted as a defect which will be added in the next major release. Defect # 88297

Comment: Hi Vipin, Exactly my point. It works for normal text values but not for keywords. For now I have managed to prefix the keywords with numbers. I have prefixed '00' to default value I want in component and it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

Default value assignment of multi value fields only works for the first instance of that field, since as I explained in my answer [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/default-value-in-drop-down-list-of-embeddable-multivalued-field-is-appearing-inc#2228) the default value logic only kicks in once per Schema load.

So the reason why you are getting the first value of your dropdown assigned on all the additional fields you create, is simply because that is the first value in the list and the field is mandatory (else you would have an empty field).

This behaviour is by design, and there isn't much you can do to change it other than a UI extension I believe, which won't be trivial.

Comment: Hi Bart thanks and agreed...However it should have been consistent for normal text as well as keywords as mentioned by Vipin.

Comment: The hotfix and the info Vipin gives about the defect is news to me ;o)